# One useful function about make vertex smooth

Tags: modeling, vertices

In this video the author first select many vertex which he wanted to adjust then hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Accent_Grave</kbd> then select 3 (blue one button) and a curve appear to make the vertex in a line smooth, at same time with three points in the curve he can easily adjust the position of many vertex smoothly.

I don't know how to do that. Is it some addon or just a function in Blender?

[Video at minute 44:00](https://youtu.be/eUQ4HSCYJfg?t=2640)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Might be Looptools?

Comment: No, the looptool doesnt has this funcation.

Comment: I had found the answer and yes it is one addon named Mira tools.